# Design UserControl with Textbox and Label with Properties in grid

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, user-controls, custom-controls

[Check the image of form and see the below code to get that functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mRoA.png)
Here is some code which i had done.
I am working on user control library project and i drag a label and textbox on it.

```
Please check the code 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public partial class CustomTextbox: UserControl
    {

        public enum Directions
        {
            Left, Right, Top, Bottom
        }

        [Description("Define the Text Property of label")]
        public string Description { 
            get 
            { 
                return label1.Text; 
            }

            set
            {
                label1.Text = value;
            }
        }

        [Description("Define the location of label")]
        public Point LabelLocation
        {
            get
            {
                return label1.Location;
            }
            set
            {
                label1.Location = value;
            }
        }

        [Description("Define the location of Textbox")]
        public Point TextboxLocation
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox1.Location;
            }
            set
            {
                textBox1.Location = value;
            }
        }
        [Description("Set Password Character Input in Textbox")]
        public char PasswordChar
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox1.PasswordChar;
            }

            set
            {
                textBox1.PasswordChar = value;
            }
        }

        [Description("Set the Multiline feature of Textbox")]
        public bool MultiLine
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox1.Multiline;
            }
            set
            {
                textBox1.Multiline = value;
            }
        }

        public CustomTextbox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I had declare an enum name direction so that i can change the position of label control as per value selected in Property Grid (left, right, down, up) and as per selected value label should align in project where i used the control dll.
Similarly i also want to create events for textbox like text validating and other important events of the controls.

How can i do this. Please suggest?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exactly does the selected enum value changes? To expose events of the textbox you should handle them in your user control and raise the same events from your user control.

Comment: Do not call UserControls CustomControls (and vice versa)!!! They are totally different things. The former an (almost Form-like) container and latter a subclass of a normal control..

Comment: Dear Zohar, I am actulally trying to create my own toolkit. Can you help me out as this one is the basic control required for my project.

Comment: Dear @TaW , i had updated an attachment what exactly I am trying to create.

Comment: I could imagine from the code that you are creating a UserControl. NOT a Customcontrol. Both __Title and Tag still are wrong__ about that. The main thing is to create a set of interactions to pass from the members (textbox and label) to the UC. [Here is a discussion on how to use UCs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965343/c-sharp-winform-custom-grid-layout/34968221#34968221)

Comment: Dear @TaW, this is not the same. May be i am confised in between custom control and user control but the point is more clear if see the image i had attached now. I want to create a control which is combination of two controls one is textbox and another is label. My base control is textbox and i am going to use textbox in my project and that control contains label with it and some additional properties like i created an enum for aligning the label with textbox in custom direction.

Comment: _this is not the same_ indeed and I never said it is. - _My base control is textbox_ No it isn't. Your base control is UserControl: `public partial class CustomTextbox: UserControl`. The link is meant as a help to understand UCs. Using UC is the recommended approach. Subclassing TextBox let alone nesting a Label in it would be a bad idea for several reasons..

Comment: Dear @TaW, please suggest me what to do to achieve this because i am completely confused. How could i achieve this functionality please suggest me the steps.

Comment: You are on a good way and if you add Dhaval's answer you will get events to work.as well..

Comment: Thanks @TaW, i am working on Dhaval's suggestion he gave me. But some points i am not able to achieve. Like textbox multiline property is not working. Similarly i am unable to create a custom property for label for its alignment as per directions defined.

Comment: Well they should work. Note that turning on MuliLine alone  will not make the height any larger.. You may want to add the alignment code to the question..

Comment: Dear @TaW, i tried all possible properties settings but i am unable to achive following properties even i had also created events for the control. Iam not able to change the height and width of control on change of size and location property of base control as well as I am creating a property name flow direction which is based on defined enum which i want to show in grid for label control for label alignment around textbox. Can you please suggest some links or some code to achieve this.

Comment: Did you set any anchor or Dock values?

Comment: I tried to set dock properties but it won't work.

Comment: You should not set any Dock  value as it will take over control of size from you!

Answer (score 4):

As par my understanding you need your own custom event from user control.

First define delegates and events in your user control as follow.

```
public delegate void TextChangeDelegate(object obj, string str);
public event TextChangeDelegate TextChanged;
```

Now in your user control you need to rise this event from your custom condition.

```
if(this.TextChanged != null)
{
    this.TextChanged.Invoke(this, textBox1.Text);
}
```

Use this in you form where you use this as follow.

```
userControl.TextChanged += UserControl_TextChanged;
```

Comment: Yes I need it apart of that i need properties of label also in same control.

Comment: I updated an image so that u can get idea about my requirement.

Comment: You can define property in your user control that will available in property box.

public Font LabelFont { get; set; }

Comment: I tried the same but it is not working properly.  I got the tab in property Grid as i defined their but the property grid is not showing the properties of base control how could i set my base control as textbox and add label as extra control and relate their properties together.

Comment: You need to add separate properties like font, fore color, backcolor ...etc whatever you need in your control and apply that value to label and text box accordingly.

Comment: I am not going to enter the value of label in textbox both are acting as different control like user form label and textbox but for better designing and UI standard i want to use these two controls as a single control. Please check the updated image.